# how to create port forwarding inside a dockerfile

Tags: docker

I am installing application on docker container which needs to port 8080

To be forward from the host to the container,i have started the container with:

```
docker run -p 8080:8080 "image id"
```

I am able to get to the application inside the docker container via browser using the below address :

docker_parent_host:8080

i need to see the container ports like this:

```
docker port 7d04524erte

3306/tcp -> 0.0.0.0:3306
80/tcp -> 0.0.0.0:80
8080/tcp -> 0.0.0.0:8080
```

i have tried to use expose in the dockerfile but is not giving me the same results,its giving me :

```
80/tcp
```

how can i get the definition of port forwarding  in the dockerfile same as mentioning -p 8080 ?

Answer (score 8):

> How can I get the definition of port forwarding in the Dockerfile same as mentioning `-p 8080`?

You can't...

With the Dockerfile you can only expose the port to the host (i.e: using [`EXPOSE`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#expose)) - you cannot automatically forward it as well.

The `-P` (or `--publish-all`) option will forward all `EXPOSE`'d ports for you, but this is still not necessarily ideal, as it will use random ports on this host interfaces (use `docker port ${CONTAINER}` to check).

---

You can however automate it using [Docker Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/gettingstarted/).

For example, you might have the following in [`docker-compose.yml`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v2/):

```
version: '2'
services:
    myservice:
        restart: "no"

        build: .

        ports:
            - 8080:8080/tcp
```

Then run `docker-compose up -d myservice`.